# How do you find the Taylor expansion of $\sinh(x)?$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series, taylor-expansion

I understand how to find the Maclaurin expansion of $\sinh(x)$ and that it is equal to (1)$$\sinh(x)=\sum^\infty_{n=0}\frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}\tag1$$
However, I am having trouble deriving the Taylor's series for $\sinh(x).$ My method is as follows:
$$f(x)=\sinh(x)=a_0 +a_1(x-a)+a_2(x-a)^2+a_3(x-a)^3+...+a_n(x-a)^n+...\Rightarrow f(a)=sinh(a)=a_0$$
$$f^{(1)}(x)=a_1+2a_2(x-a)+3a_3(x-a)²+...\Rightarrow f^{(1)}(a)=cosh(a)=a_1$$
$$f^{(2)}(x)=2!\cdot a_2+2\cdot3a_3(x-a)+...\Rightarrow f^{(2)}(a) = sinh(a)=2!\cdot a_2$$
Repeating this process gives me an expansion for sinh(x) shown in (2)
$$\sinh(x)=\sinh(a)+\cosh(a)(x-a)+\frac{\sinh(a)}{2!}(x-a)²+\frac{\cosh(a)}{3!}(x-a)^3+...\tag2$$
What is missing with this process as shouldn't the Taylor expansion of $\sinh(x)$ be as shown in (3)?
$$\sinh(x)=(x-a)+\frac{(x-a)^3}{3!}+\frac{(x-a)^5}{5!}+...+\frac{(x-a)^n}{n!}+...\tag3$$

Comment: Thank you I have changed it.

Comment: (2) is the correct Taylor series at $a$. Why do you think that it should be (3)?

Comment: $(3)$ is $\sinh(x-a),$ not $\sinh x.$

Comment: $$\sinh(x)=\sinh(x-a)\cosh(a)+\sinh(a)\cosh(x-a)$$ So you can find the Taylor series for $\sinh x$ around $x=a$ using the Maclaurin series of $\sinh$ and $\cosh.$